# Practical examples to determinism and periodicity of analog signals?

Tags: analog, signal

What I understand from deterministic signal is that we can define it as a function. Same thing is valid for a periodic signal. But periodicity and determinism are are treated as independent categories in analog or digital signal processing if I'm not completely wrong. I saw many definitions purely abstract or mathematical.

Instead of going into abstraction too much is it possible to give a real life example to these signals?

For instance, if I set the function generator to output a sine wave I would call this signal as "deterministic and periodic". But besides this I cannot imagine others as practical examples.

So to me the easiest one was "deterministic periodic signal" which is the ideal function generator output.

Can we give a similar examples to a "deterministic aperiodic",  "non-deterministic periodic" and "non-deterministic aperiodic" signal? Some of these might not exist but I'm trying to relate these to real and prectical examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we're working in a gray area here, since notions such as "deterministic" and "periodic" are already theoretical constructs. For example by their definition they typically presume that the value of the signal can be specified from \$- \infty < t < \infty\$, and that can never be true for any "practical" signal. So here we are going to make some approximations.

**Deterministic and periodic**: like you said this is pretty easy. A sine wave, for example. (As the above, it is only "deterministic and periodic" while the function generator is on and we ignore the noise, but that's kinda what we mean by "practical" here.)

**Deterministic and aperiodic**: well a DC voltage would probably qualify, but that's academic and debatable. Probably a useful real-world example would be a decaying voltage in an RC circuit \$v(t) = v_0e^{-t \over RC}\$ for \$t \geq 0\$. The value is always changing but never repeats.

**Non-deterministic, but periodic**: pretty sure this is impossible, in any practical sense. If we cannot predict the future value of the signal, then how can we say that it repeats? You *could* meet this definition with a looser definition of "periodic", for example an FM signal where the specific frequency randomly varies over time.

**Non-deterministic and aperiodic**: any noise signal meets this definition. Even some function generators will have a noise generator output. Or you can build a simple [avalanche diode noise generator](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3469) and create your own non-deterministic aperiodic signal.

Comment: Amazing this cleared up my confusions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding deterministic: you could argue/wonder whether the *observer* to fails comprehend the signal and fails to fit it in any mathematical system or that the *signal* really is too eluvise to be fit in any mathematical system.

Some examples:

**deterministic aperiodic**
 - step signal
 - ramp signal

**non-deterministic aperiodic**
 - noise

**non-deterministic periodic**
- can't think of an independent signal (apart from noise on a periodic signal)

Comment: EMI issues are often being occused of being non-deterministic ...